# Why does file become larger after the copy action by Maven copy-resources plugin?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I use `maven-war-plugin` to get a war package and then use `maven-resources-plugin` to copy this war file to another dictionary, the war file becomes larger from 4M to 8M.

Here is the POM,

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>FirstIssue</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>../../GTISServer/iis-gtis-web/src/main/webapp/downloadResource/firstIssue</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>FirstIssue.war</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run Maven:install in IDEA, I got two war files, one created by `maven-war-plugin` is 4M, and the other one created by `maven-resources-plugin` is 8M.

And I cannot open this 8M war with any zip tools.

[image: from 4M to 8M]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the `<filtering>` tag. It is recommended not to filter binary files.

Pls. see it here : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html